# How to choose the first value then ignor rest?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with data as follows:

```
id  activity  amount   
1    unknown   20           
2    storage   20          
3    storage   20          
4    swift     20          
5    delivery  50          
6    storage   20
```

I want to create a query which gives me the "calculated" sum.
for the example above.. the desired result is:

```
id  activity  amount   calculatedsum
1    unknown   20           0
2    storage   20          20
3    storage   20          20
4    swift     20          20
5    delivery  50          70         (had 20 and 50 arrived)
6    storage   20          70
```

the logic is simple..
find the first row which is 'storage', that is the `calculatedsum`. when encounter a row with 'delivery' add it and that is the new `calculatedsum`.

This is what I tried to do:

```
select *,
       sum(case when activity  = 'Storage' then amount
                when activity  = 'delivery' then + amount
                else 0
           end)  over (order by id)
from  A
```

however this doesn't work...

how can I get the expected result?

Edit:  id is a colum which was created by: `select row_number() over (order by .... nulls last) as id`
the table contains the result from the query... and eveytime the query runs the table is reseted by it... so the id is always the actual row number.

Comment: Where does `swift` come from?

Comment: how are u getting activity `unknown` and `swift` when you have not given them in input? Please create [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with correct data

Answer (score 0):

If you are only counting the first `'storage'`, then you need to identify it.  You can do that using `row_number()`:

```
select *,
       sum(case when activity = 'Storage' and seqnum = 1 then amount
                when activity  = 'delivery' then amount
                else 0
           end) over (order by id)
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by activity order by id) as seqnum
      from A a
     ) a
```

A totally weird way of doing this without a subquery, if we assuming that the amounts for `storage` are all the same:

```
select *,
       (sum(case when activity  = 'delivery' then amount
                 else 0
             end) over (order by id) + 
         min(case when activity = 'storage' then amount else 0
             end) over (order by id)
       )
from A a;
```

Comment: is there a way to do that using only the Select? I rather not touching the from statment. This new column is added to a huge query... I need it as simple as possible even if performence is slower.   Note: ID is already row_number()  this is how I generated it.

Comment: why is `select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by activity order by id) as seqnum
      from A a`
important if you already have that information in the id column... id is infact row_number

Comment: @SMW . . . Because that identifies the first row that has `storage` as the activity.